# Obtaining the child values randomly in JSON

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jsr223

I have a JSON like below: I need to extract the Options -> Child as a Random and also Values within the options as randomly. How can we achieve in jmeter ?

```
{
"id":37,
"merchant_id":"39",
"title":"Parker Pens",
"subtitle":null,
"price":1000,
"description":null,
"images":[  ],
"image_thumbs":[  ],
"options":[  
 {  
     "code":"color",
     "label":"Color",
     "extra_info":"",
     "values":[  
        {  },
        {  },
        {  }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "code":"size",
     "label":"Size",
     "extra_info":"",
     "values":[  
        {  },
        {  },
        {  }
     ]
  }
],"options_available":[  
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  },
  {  }
], "custom_options":[  

 ]
 }
```

I have to fetch the child of options randomly . In that i have to fetch the value of "Code" and its associated value within the "Value" . 
Help is appreciated and useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a little bit vague as you haven't indicated what is the desired output format. One of the solutions would be using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) in order to obtain the random value from random `options` array like:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult

def options = JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$.options')
def randomOption = options.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, options.size()))
def values = randomOption.get('values')
def randomValue = values.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, values.size())) as String
vars.put('randomValue', randomValue)
```

References:

- [Jayway JsonPath - A Java DSL for reading JSON documents](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Comment: I have to fetch the child of options randomly . In that i have to fetch the value of "Code" and its associated value within the "Value".

Comment: Updated my Question